# Viewport meta tag remove bug

Tags: viewport, meta

My web page has no «meta» viewport tag absolutely.

I have created my own «meta» viewport tag dynamically:

```
var viewportMeta = document.createElement('meta');
    viewportMeta.setAttribute('id', 'myMeta');
    viewportMeta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
    viewportMeta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');
```

and appended it to the «head» (after some user actions):

```
document.head.appendChild(viewportMeta);
```

Then (after user clicks on some button) I need to remove "myMeta" «meta» tag from «head»:

```
var myMeta = document.getElementById('myMeta');
document.head.removeChild(myMeta);
```

And it removes, 100%! Checked with desktop browser and with Adobe Edge Inspect Weinre on iPad.

But the whole page does not go to it's previous state! Whole page stays the same, like it has «meta» viewport tag with all defined properties in "viewportMeta" object.

So, is there a way to remove «meta» viewport tag completely? Any ideas?

(This issue is on iPad's Safari and Chrome browsers. Tried not to remove «meta» tag but just changed it's «content» property — no success. Did not checked on Android devices and browsers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should restore the original value of viewport meta tag

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test dynamic view port</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="turnOn">on</button>
    <button id="turnOff">off</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function turnOnDeviceViewport() {

            removeMetaIfExist();

            var viewportMeta = document.createElement('meta');
            viewportMeta.setAttribute('id', 'myMeta');
            viewportMeta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
            viewportMeta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no');

            document.head.appendChild(viewportMeta);
            alert("click");
        }

        function turnOffDeviceViewport() {

            removeMetaIfExist();

            var viewportMeta = document.createElement('meta');
            viewportMeta.setAttribute('id', 'myMeta');
            viewportMeta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport');
            viewportMeta.setAttribute('content', 'width=980, user-scalable=yes');

            document.head.appendChild(viewportMeta);
            alert("click");
        }

        function removeMetaIfExist() {

            var metaElement = document.getElementById("myMeta");
            if (metaElement) document.head.removeChild(metaElement);
            alert("removed");
        }

        document.getElementById("turnOn").addEventListener("click", turnOnDeviceViewport, false);
        document.getElementById("turnOff").addEventListener("click", turnOffDeviceViewport, false);

    </script>
</body>
```

You can find details about viewport meta default values on Apple's developer website:
[Safari HTML Reference: Supported Meta Tags](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)

EDIT: the default **viewport** value "width=980, user-scalable=yes" might not be the same for all devices and browsers so for a complete solution you will need to identify the browser you are running on and set the default value accordingly

Comment: I tested your advice — no success. It absolutely not updating from "width=device-width" to its default width or any width less than container width (it resizes to 1200 px, for example, but not to 980 px). It changes "user-scalable=no" to "user-scalable=yes", this works perfect. But no success in updating "device-width" to any default widths.

Comment: I just tested it on Chrome with Android 4.0.4 and it works. I will update later for Apple devices.

Comment: @ArielDeil Once we remove viewport meta tag then can we able to add them? I mean I need to add and remove meta tag on button clicks. I have java file code also like below WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings();
  settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  settings.setSupportZoom(true);
  settings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.MEDIUM); Can u please check this??